# Nativescript-Angular code sharing: How do I create platform specific modules?

Tags: nativescript, angular2-nativescript, nativescript-angular, nativescript-codesharing

Imagine I have OrderComponent and CustomerComponent that represent two screens.

In the web version you can create a new customer while in the order screen by launching the customer component inside a popup. So OrderComponent references CustomerComponent directly in the template. So I have to keep both in the same  **FeaturesModule** for this to work.

On the other hand in the Nativescript mobile version, there is no such capability and so the two components/screens are completely independent, so I would like to put them in 2 separate modules: **OrderModule**, and **CustomerModule**. And lazy load them so the app launches faster.

In my real application of course it's not just 2 components but several dozens so the mobile app performance is a more pressing issue.

When I try to add a module file with the tns extension like this: **order.module.tns.ts**, without the corresponding web file, it seems as if the NativeScript bundler is not picking it up, I get the following error:

```
ERROR: C:\...\src\app\features\orders\orders.module.ts is missing from the TypeScript compilation. Please make sure it is in your tsconfig via the 'files' or 'include' property.
 at AngularCompilerPlugin.getCompiledFile (C:\Users\...\node_modules\@ngtools\webpack\src\angular_compiler_plugin.js:753:23)
    at plugin.done.then (C:\Users\...\node_modules\@ngtools\webpack\src\loader.js:41:31)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
 @ ../$$_lazy_route_resource lazy namespace object ./features/measurement-units/measurement-units.module
 @ ../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js
 @ ../node_modules/nativescript-angular/platform.js
 @ ./main.ns.ts
```

But according to the [docs](https://docs.nativescript.org/code-sharing/platform-specific-components), all I have to do to make a nativescript specific component is add it with the tns extension. Is there another step to make this work for module files?? Help is appreciated

**Update**
Here is my tsconfig.tns.json

```
{
  "extends": "./tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "es2015",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "paths": {
      "~/*": [
          "src/*"
      ],
      "*": [
          "./node_modules/tns-core-modules/*",
          "./node_modules/*"
      ]
    }    
  }
}
```

**Update 2**
My webpack.config.js:

```
    const { join, relative, resolve, sep } = require("path");

const webpack = require("webpack");
const nsWebpack = require("nativescript-dev-webpack");
const nativescriptTarget = require("nativescript-dev-webpack/nativescript-target");
const { nsReplaceBootstrap } = require("nativescript-dev-webpack/transformers/ns-replace-bootstrap");
const CleanWebpackPlugin = require("clean-webpack-plugin");
const CopyWebpackPlugin = require("copy-webpack-plugin");
const { BundleAnalyzerPlugin } = require("webpack-bundle-analyzer");
const { NativeScriptWorkerPlugin } = require("nativescript-worker-loader/NativeScriptWorkerPlugin");
const UglifyJsPlugin = require("uglifyjs-webpack-plugin");
const { AngularCompilerPlugin } = require("@ngtools/webpack");

module.exports = env => {
    // Add your custom Activities, Services and other Android app components here.
    const appComponents = [
        "tns-core-modules/ui/frame",
        "tns-core-modules/ui/frame/activity",
    ];

    const platform = env && (env.android && "android" || env.ios && "ios");
    if (!platform) {
        throw new Error("You need to provide a target platform!");
    }

    const projectRoot = __dirname;

    // Default destination inside platforms/<platform>/...
    const dist = resolve(projectRoot, nsWebpack.getAppPath(platform, projectRoot));
    const appResourcesPlatformDir = platform === "android" ? "Android" : "iOS";

    const {
        // The 'appPath' and 'appResourcesPath' values are fetched from
        // the nsconfig.json configuration file
        // when bundling with `tns run android|ios --bundle`.
        appPath = "app",
        appResourcesPath = "app/App_Resources",

        // You can provide the following flags when running 'tns run android|ios'
        aot, // --env.aot
        snapshot, // --env.snapshot
        uglify, // --env.uglify
        report, // --env.report
        sourceMap, // --env.sourceMap
        hmr, // --env.hmr,
    } = env;
    const externals = (env.externals || []).map((e) => { // --env.externals
        return new RegExp(e + ".*");
    });

    const appFullPath = resolve(projectRoot, appPath);
    const appResourcesFullPath = resolve(projectRoot, appResourcesPath);

    const entryModule = `${nsWebpack.getEntryModule(appFullPath)}.ts`;
    const entryPath = `.${sep}${entryModule}`;

    const ngCompilerPlugin = new AngularCompilerPlugin({
        hostReplacementPaths: nsWebpack.getResolver([platform, "tns"]),
        platformTransformers: aot ? [nsReplaceBootstrap(() => ngCompilerPlugin)] : null,
        mainPath: resolve(appPath, entryModule),
        tsConfigPath: join(__dirname, "tsconfig.tns.json"),
        skipCodeGeneration: !aot,
        sourceMap: !!sourceMap,
    });

    const config = {
        mode: uglify ? "production" : "development",
        context: appFullPath,
        externals,
        watchOptions: {
            ignored: [
                appResourcesFullPath,
                // Don't watch hidden files
                "**/.*",
            ]
        },
        target: nativescriptTarget,
        entry: {
            bundle: entryPath,
        },
        output: {
            pathinfo: false,
            path: dist,
            libraryTarget: "commonjs2",
            filename: "[name].js",
            globalObject: "global",
        },
        resolve: {
            extensions: [".ts", ".js", ".scss", ".css"],
            // Resolve {N} system modules from tns-core-modules
            modules: [
                resolve(__dirname, "node_modules/tns-core-modules"),
                resolve(__dirname, "node_modules"),
                "node_modules/tns-core-modules",
                "node_modules",
            ],
            alias: {
                '~': appFullPath
            },
            symlinks: true
        },
        resolveLoader: {
            symlinks: false
        },
        node: {
            // Disable node shims that conflict with NativeScript
            "http": false,
            "timers": false,
            "setImmediate": false,
            "fs": "empty",
            "__dirname": false,
        },
        devtool: sourceMap ? "inline-source-map" : "none",
        optimization: {
            splitChunks: {
                cacheGroups: {
                    vendor: {
                        name: "vendor",
                        chunks: "all",
                        test: (module, chunks) => {
                            const moduleName = module.nameForCondition ? module.nameForCondition() : '';
                            return /[\\/]node_modules[\\/]/.test(moduleName) ||
                                appComponents.some(comp => comp === moduleName);
                        },
                        enforce: true,
                    },
                }
            },
            minimize: !!uglify,
            minimizer: [
                new UglifyJsPlugin({
                    parallel: true,
                    cache: true,
                    uglifyOptions: {
                        output: {
                            comments: false,
                        },
                        compress: {
                            // The Android SBG has problems parsing the output
                            // when these options are enabled
                            'collapse_vars': platform !== "android",
                            sequences: platform !== "android",
                        }
                    }
                })
            ],
        },
        module: {
            rules: [
                {
                    test: new RegExp(entryPath),
                    use: [
                        // Require all Android app components
                        platform === "android" && {
                            loader: "nativescript-dev-webpack/android-app-components-loader",
                            options: { modules: appComponents }
                        },

                        {
                            loader: "nativescript-dev-webpack/bundle-config-loader",
                            options: {
                                angular: true,
                                loadCss: !snapshot, // load the application css if in debug mode
                            }
                        },
                    ].filter(loader => !!loader)
                },

                { test: /\.html$|\.xml$/, use: "raw-loader" },

                // tns-core-modules reads the app.css and its imports using css-loader
                {
                    test: /[\/|\\]app\.css$/,
                    use: {
                        loader: "css-loader",
                        options: { minimize: false, url: false },
                    }
                },
                {
                    test: /[\/|\\]app\.scss$/,
                    use: [
                        { loader: "css-loader", options: { minimize: false, url: false } },
                        "sass-loader"
                    ]
                },

                // Angular components reference css files and their imports using raw-loader
                { test: /\.css$/, exclude: /[\/|\\]app\.css$/, use: "raw-loader" },
                { test: /\.scss$/, exclude: /[\/|\\]app\.scss$/, use: ["raw-loader", "resolve-url-loader", "sass-loader"] },

                {
                    test: /(?:\.ngfactory\.js|\.ngstyle\.js|\.ts)$/,
                    use: [
                        "nativescript-dev-webpack/moduleid-compat-loader",
                        "@ngtools/webpack",
                    ]
                },

                // Mark files inside `@angular/core` as using SystemJS style dynamic imports.
                // Removing this will cause deprecation warnings to appear.
                {
                    test: /[\/\\]@angular[\/\\]core[\/\\].+\.js$/,
                    parser: { system: true },
                },
            ],
        },
        plugins: [
            // Define useful constants like TNS_WEBPACK
            new webpack.DefinePlugin({
                "global.TNS_WEBPACK": "true",
                "process": undefined,
            }),
            // Remove all files from the out dir.
            new CleanWebpackPlugin([`${dist}/**/*`]),
            // Copy native app resources to out dir.
            new CopyWebpackPlugin([
                {
                    from: `${appResourcesFullPath}/${appResourcesPlatformDir}`,
                    to: `${dist}/App_Resources/${appResourcesPlatformDir}`,
                    context: projectRoot
                },
            ]),
            // Copy assets to out dir. Add your own globs as needed.
            new CopyWebpackPlugin([
                { from: "fonts/**" },
                { from: "**/*.jpg" },
                { from: "**/*.png" },
            ], { ignore: [`${relative(appPath, appResourcesFullPath)}/**`] }),
            // Generate a bundle starter script and activate it in package.json
            new nsWebpack.GenerateBundleStarterPlugin([
                "./vendor",
                "./bundle",
            ]),
            // For instructions on how to set up workers with webpack
            // check out https://github.com/nativescript/worker-loader
            new NativeScriptWorkerPlugin(),
            ngCompilerPlugin,
            // Does IPC communication with the {N} CLI to notify events when running in watch mode.
            new nsWebpack.WatchStateLoggerPlugin(),
        ],
    };


    if (report) {
        // Generate report files for bundles content
        config.plugins.push(new BundleAnalyzerPlugin({
            analyzerMode: "static",
            openAnalyzer: false,
            generateStatsFile: true,
            reportFilename: resolve(projectRoot, "report", `report.html`),
            statsFilename: resolve(projectRoot, "report", `stats.json`),
        }));
    }

    if (snapshot) {
        config.plugins.push(new nsWebpack.NativeScriptSnapshotPlugin({
            chunk: "vendor",
            angular: true,
            requireModules: [
                "reflect-metadata",
                "@angular/platform-browser",
                "@angular/core",
                "@angular/common",
                "@angular/router",
                "nativescript-angular/platform-static",
                "nativescript-angular/router",
            ],
            projectRoot,
            webpackConfig: config,
        }));
    }

    if (hmr) {
        config.plugins.push(new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin());
    }

    return config;
};
```

Comment: Btw, I'm using Nativescript 5.1.0, Angular 7, and I get the error above when I try to navigate to the lazy OrdersModule in the mobile app

Comment: Can you show us your tsconfig and webpack.config?

Comment: @Manoj I included tsconfig.tns.json. I did not find any file called webpack.config. My project is the default core sharing project generated with this command: ng new -c=@nativescript/schematics project-name --shared

Comment: @Manoj my bad. webpack.config.js was not showing in VS Code, but I found it in file explorer. I included it in my question as well

Comment: Are you sure the `nsext` in your `nsconfig.json` reads `".tns"`?